# What do the four castles on the flag of Ibiza represent?

Tags: spain, flags, mediterranean

The flag of [Ibiza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibiza) consists of four horizontal, red stripes on a yellow background. Each corner of the flag contains a seven-tower castle above a wave.

[image: flag of Ibiza]

What is the significance of the four castles? Were there four famous strongholds in the history of Ibiza?

Comment: It is worth noting that all the [flags of the Baleric Islands](http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/es-ib.html) feature castles on the Aragonese flag.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Also the flags of Aragon, Catalunya and Valencia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the website [ibizaisla.es](http://www.ibizaisla.es/blog/y-si-ibiza-se-independiza.html),

> The flag of Ibiza features the flag of the Crown of Aragon with four
>   castles over the sea, in allusion to the four *quartons* the island
>   was divided into after its conquest.

*Quartó* (plural *quartons*) was the Catalan name of each of the four quarters the island was divided into after the conquest of Ibiza and Formentera by the Aragonese in 1235 (Catalan Wikipedia article about the *quartons* [here](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quart%C3%B3)).

Interestingly enough, a couple of PDF documents ([1](http://www.estudiseivissencs.cat/bo/arx/comunicats/38/sobresimbolscivicsiee.pdf) and [2](http://www.estudiseivissencs.cat/bo/arx/comunicats/37/informeieesimbolscivicsconselldeivissa2007.pdf)) at the [Institute of Ibicene Studies](http://www.estudiseivissencs.cat/) (*Institut d'Estudis Eivissencs* in Catalan) mention that according to official documents from the time of the flag's creation in 1979, its basis had been an alleged flag of the ancient University of Ibiza (no mention was made of why it had four castles). According to the said institute, there's no trace of any flag of the ancient University of Ibiza either, so in 2007 there was a proposal for changing the flag for another, more coherent one from a heraldic point of view, but was ultimately cancelled.

Comment: Very interesting! Can you link to those PDF documents?

Comment: @terminex9 I have added the links to the answer, mind they are in Catalan.